# AuthGuard and RedirectTo not working for root path

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a angular application, Which has following **URL Paths**,

- / (root)
- /courses
- /courses/create
- /courses/:id
- /auth/login

I have added **AuthGuard** for all routes except `auth/login`. `AuthGuard` redirects to `auth\login` if not authenticated.

---

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const Approutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: FullComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule) // loading from pages-routing.ts
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: PlainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'login'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

**pages-routing.ts**

```
export const PagesRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: 'courses'
            },
            {
                path: 'courses',
                component: CourseMainPageComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'My Courses'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'courses/create',
                component: CourseCreatePageComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Create Course'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'courses/:id',
                component: CourseShowPageComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Course Detail'
                }
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

**The Problem**

All routes and authGuard works fine. **But** when I enter the root URL `\`, I needed to redirect to `\courses`, But it's not working. **Also** in root URL `\` **AuthGuard is not redirecting** me to `auth\login` even.

> **NOTE**
>   I don't get any run-time or compile error.

Comment: can you make your problem of  demo  in stackblitz here?

Comment: FullComponent is loading on empty route. Try to remove component and loadChildren only.

Comment: Uhh... But The FullComponent is a main layout. Then children are loading in a certain area.. Anyway lemme try

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the [pathMatch](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#pathMatch) strategy to `full` in the route you are using to redirect. As per the docs,

> The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes. Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

Your route configuration will now look like so

```js
export const PagesRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    children: [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'courses',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    // Add other routes here
    ]
}];
```